# How to execute app DVD through Terminal of recovery flash drive?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, install, dvd

I have a Mac OS X 10.7 Lion recovery usb flash drive.  It still boots but won't install Lion anymore (an error occurred during installation). I don't have a install DVD, however the MacBookPro's were able to install El Capitan directly.

I have a Lion install dmg so there are two options: to make a bootable DVD or simply execute the dmg burned into a DVD - trying right now.

I was trying to learn some command line tasks but there are some issues.  The root is read only so I could not create a new directory and mount the DVD.  Also, I remembered there is an app to easily create a bootable DVD.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X installers downloaded from the MacAppStore before February 14, 2016 are no longer functional due to Apple's Worldwide Developer Certificate expiration.

during installation you have to set your system's clock prior to that date, with the date command, for example:

```
date 1111111115
```

and then install normally your OS X lion version on a freshly erased HD

-

to get a functional lion usb installer, just restore (with Disk Utility) InstallESD.dmg on a usb stick or burn it on a dvd

the file is inside the app bundle `"Install Mac OS X Lion.app" -> Content -> SharedSupport`

Comment: The only way it worked was creating an USB install flash drive. My optical drive was attached by an extension from second HDD caddy, and I think this device is not working properly because nothing works using it's SATA port (nor the SDD it was there, nor any DVD using a SATA optical drive). Also, the remote install didn't work even with data command.